# Set a specific column in a DataRow

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset, datacolumn

I'm trying to perform a "bulk" insert a set of rules into a table of rules. The table has the following structure:

```
RuleId int,
Rule nvarchar(256),
Domain nvarchar(256),
RuleTypeId int,
ExpirationDate DateTime
```

In my insertion function I try to set the columns of a row after I've obtained the schema of the table, but it appears that the row does not contain the specified column (**note that I don't specify the RuleId since it's auto-generated**):

```
private void InsertRulesXml(List<Rule> rules)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        using (DataTable rulesTable = GetSchemeForTable("RulesTable"))
        {
            // Add the rules to the table
            foreach (Rule rule in rules)
            {
                DataRow row = rulesTable.NewRow();

                // When I try to set the specific column it tells me that the column doesn't exist
                row["Rule"] = rule.Rule;
                row["Domain"] = rule.Domain;
                row["RuleTypeId"] = rule.RuleTypeId;
                row["ExpirationDate"] = rule.Expiration;

                rulesTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(rulesTable);

            // Convert the data to XML
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                rulesTable.WriteXml(sw, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            }

            // Insert the XML rules
            InsertUpdateRulesXml(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the function that gets the schema for the specified table:

```
private DataTable GetSchemeForTable(string tableName)
{
    DataTable ret = null;

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetContentScraperSqlConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 0 [{0}].* FROM [{0}] WHERE 1 = 2;", tableName);
            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
            {
                ret = reader.GetSchemaTable();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in GetSchemeForTable: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Problem: **When I try to set the specific column it tells me that the column doesn't exist.**
Exception Message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Column 'Rule' does not belong to table SchemaTable.
```

I suspect that the getting the table schema does not actually give me `Rule` table, but the `SchemaTable`. What I really want to get is the DataTable which corresponds to the `Rule` table (i.e. it has the same schema).

Question: **What's the proper way to set the column values in a row given a list of records?**

Comment: why not check and see what the column names are? You should be able to do something like "foreach (DataColumn col in rulesTable.Columns) { Console.WriteLine(col.Name); }" Maybe a weird name is being autogenerated. Another option would just be to use the column indexes.

Comment: rulesTable  would have columns like ColumnName, ColumnOrdinal, ColumnSize, NumericPrecision and so on. It represents the schema table not the table (RuleTable) itself.

Comment: @amit_g yah, that's the problem that I'm facing... how do I get the actual `RulesTable` table itself?

Comment: Another quick thing I noticed. Your SQL query shouldn't return anything. You selected TOP 0 (as in no rows). I think you might need some results for reader.GetSchemaTable() to work.

Comment: You will have to create the table dynamically using the row values from the rulesTable.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson that shouldn't matter: I get the same results whether I select top 0 or top 1.

Comment: @Lirik I added a possible solution for you that does not require database access. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetSchemaTable` does not do what it looks like you're expecting it to do.  It returns a `DataTable` where the rows are the columns of the source table and the columns are metadata about those columns.

If you want to get an "empty" `DataTable` with the schema of the given table, change your function to:

```
private DataTable GetSchemeForTable(string tableName)
{
    DataTable ret = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE 1 = 2;", tableName);
        using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            ret.Load(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in GetSchemeForTable: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        connection.Dispose();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

notice I took out the `using` block since you're disposing of the connection in your finally block anyways (which is essentially what `using` does).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use something like this to generate your table:

```
GenerateDataTable(typeof(Rule));

private DataTable GenerateRulesDataTable(Type type)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // build table columns
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        Type colType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn(propInfo.Name, colType);
        table.Columns.Add(col);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: not sure, but I think that update will not work if DataTable is created that way

Comment: I think you should actually be fine. The names for each column is taken from your Rule object. So long as you make sure to keep the object consistent with your database, you should be fine. Although you might run into problems if you let .NET do all your sql query management.

Comment: This is a good solution and it would work provided that the Rule class contains properties with matching names (i.e. the names of the columns match the names of the properties). It's not the case in my situation, but it's definitely a valid approach. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

GetSchemaTable doesn't return DataTable with structure identical as one returned by DataReader select, it returs a table with same schema (ColumnName, ColumnSize, etc) and your schema is in DataTable rows.

In your case you should get DataTable with this select and then you will get empty RulesTable. That way you will be able to insert new rows into a returned DataTable (rulesTable in your case) and do a Update back to database.